# MinGW: How can I find package for path

Tags: mingw

I am using MinGW Installation Manager. Imagine that I know that there is a utility (let's call it `/bin/exampleTool`) in one of the available MinGW packages, but I don't know which one. Is there any way to find this package using the above information?

Note: On Debian I can use `apt-file`. After installing `apt-file` I can issue `apt-file update` to download the package - path mapping then I can call `apt-file search /bin/exampleTool` to find the package which installs it.

I'm looking for a similar tool or a website which I could query the same way but in the realm of MinGW.